# Is it possible to query when a specific field changed in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, workitem

I have a DateTime field (MyDTField) in my Azure DevOps instance (I am an admin on it, so I can change its schema if necessary). I would like to write a query that returns any items where the above field (MyDTField) changed in the last 7 days. Is this possible to do?

For e.g. the built in "Changed Date" field allows us to write a similar query, but that returns work times where any field value changed. I want to get items where a specific field changed within a specified time period.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set up a query like as below to see if it can work as expected.

[image]

To view more details, you can see:

- [**Query history and discussion fields**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/history-and-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)
- [**Operators and macros supported for each data type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-index-quick-ref?view=azure-devops#operators-and-macros-supported-for-each-data-type)

**[UPDATE]**

As a workaround, you can try like as below on each of the work item types that have the **`MyDTField`** field:

1. Add another custom Date/Time field, for example "**`MyDTField Latest change Date`**" field.
   [image]
2. Add a work item rule like this. With this rule, once the **`MyDTField`** field changed, the value of the **`MyDTField Latest change Date`** field will be automatically changed to the current date/time.
   [image]
3. Set up the query like as this. With this query, you will get the list of work items as your expectation.
   [image]

Comment: That means though that if the MyDTField was ever changed, it would show up in the results as long as something else changed in the item, even if the change that happened within the last 7 days had nothing to do with that field, right?

Comment: Hi @Snooks, 

Yes, that's correct. Due to there is no any available clause of work item query to filter the content of the latest change on a specific field, this should be the range we can get closest to your demand.

However, I also have a workaround that can totally meet your demand. I have updated my above answer with this workaround. Please check it.

Comment: Ah that's perfect, I think that would work for me. Thank you! For anyone that finds this answer later, the following provides an example of how this rule can be implemented as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/assign-conditional-based-values-and-rules?view=azure-devops-2020

Refer to the "WHENCHANGED" examples.

Comment: You're welcome, @Snooks. And glad that the problem no longer bothers you.